# Bounded form in complex complete manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-analytic-spaces

If $\alpha$ is a bounded form in a complex complete manifold $X$ (i.e $\sup_X|\alpha (x) |<\infty$, then $d\alpha$ is it also bounded?
Rq: if $d\alpha$ is bounded then \alpha is not necessary bounded, take for exemple $dx_1\wedge dx_2...\wedge dx_{2n} =d\Gamma$ on $\mathbb{C}^n.$

Comment: You are assuming that $X$ has a complete Riemannian metric? Or Finsler? Hermitian? Kaehler?

Comment: X is a hermitian manifold

Answer (score 1):

On $\mathbb{C}$, try $\omega=\sin(|z|^2) \, dz$.